# Can I run cables into the side of my breaker panel?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel

The top of my electric panel is fairly full with cables. When I add another circuit, can I run the cable through a knockout on the side of the panel or do I need conduit to protect the wires?

Comment: Is the panel occupying the entire stud bay, width-wise, or is it surface-mounted?

Answer (score 3):

The NEC doesn't have a problem with cable entering a panel from different knockouts. In fact that's why they're there. But the entry point must be bushed to prevent the sharp edge of the knockout from cutting and damaging the insulation from the conductor and comes with a strain relief method. This can usually be purchased in any big box or even a local hardware store in the electrical section. They come in various types and manufacturers but the store should have someone there to help you select one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just be sure to thread the new Romex through the bushings (both pieces) onto the wire BEFORE you make connections in your breaker box.  Otherwise, you'll need to disconnect and redo your work.  Voice of experience talking here...

Comment: For work in an existing panel I like Raco "insider" clamps/ bushings these are easy to install from the inside of the panel they protect the cable and secure it. In fact I use these for new construction also but started using them for remodels. I don't work for Raco just like the product they snap into the knockouts quickly and easily.